# Does India Have a CORS (Continuously Operating Reference Stations) Network?

Tags: gps, india, base-station

Does India have a CORS (Continuously Operating Reference Stations) network? If yes, can anybody provide more details about it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a **[link to the CORS map](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS_Map/)**.

And here's a **[link to a KMZ file](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS_Map/corsdownload?id=kmz)** of CORS sites.  It doesn't look like India has a CORS network.

It looks like most of the CORS locations are in the United States.

[image]

Here's **[the website on other GPS Augmentations](http://www.gps.gov/systems/augmentations/)**.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something similar to a CORS network, then IGS has a few stations in India:

http://igscb.jpl.nasa.gov/network/complete.html

I am looking for GNSS receivers active in India as well, hopefully a more dense network of receivers.

I would guess that there are GAGAN stations with some information but if that data is publicly available I am not sure where to find it.

Answer (score -1):

Geotrax international services set up at Indore is the first cors network to do norms project.

**Disclaimer**: I work for Geotrax

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Also, you will notice that I am about to remove the email address from your answer because that should only be provided in your [user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59873/www-geotrax-in) that signs every post.  Whenever you recommend your own product you should always add a disclaimer like I will do for you.  The requirement for this is mentioned at http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior.